# Update Observable on View Model

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to allow the users to click a checkbox to toggle a boolean property, but I can't seem to be able to actually change the underlying View Model.

Model looks like:

```
var fund = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.Id = ko.observable();
        self.name = ko.observable();
        self.ticker = ko.observable();
        self.companyId = ko.observable();
        self.status = ko.observable();
        self.number = ko.observable();
        self.addedDate = ko.observable();
        self.comment = ko.observable();
        self.companyName = ko.observable();
        self.isSalary = ko.observable(); <--
```

The property at the bottom are the properties in question.. Here's my HTML.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSalary,  click: function(data) { $root.toggleReference(data, 'SAL', 'isSalary') }" />
```

And the function on my View Model..

```
toggleReference = function (currentFund, referenceAbbrev, updateProperty) {
        alert(currentFund.Id() + " "  + referenceAbbrev + " " + updateProperty);
}
```

I've tried applying bindings after this function finishes, and also :

```
var currentValue = currentFund[updateProperty];
fund.updateProperty = updateProperty;
```

They toggle the checkbox (because I'm clicking on it), when my alert comes through, but switches back to whatever state it was in when I initially applied the bindings when the function finishes. It's like although I am trying to update it, I am never reapplying the toggled value back to the view model.

How do I specifically update this property?

Note: On the HTML, I am using an `observableArray()` since we are dealing with things in a table format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `click` binding needs to return `true`, otherwise knockout is seeing it as [an attempt to prevent the default behaviour](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action).  This should fix it:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSalary,  click: function(data) { $root.toggleReference(data, 'SAL', 'isSalary'); return true; }" />
```

[Here's a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesThorpe/dt6vsezs/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Can you elaborate a bit on your answer? Also, have you seen this elsewhere? Can you point me to where you saw it? Thanks a bunch. Will accept after time constraint is up.

Comment: @Invent-Animate It's a knockout feature - have linked to the relevant part of the docs in my answer now I've found it :)

Comment: Thanks boss. Overlooked that one!

Answer (score 0):

The checked binding should handle the viewModel updates without any additional coding.

What's the click binding for? If you just want to inspect the state, debug on the backend with Chrome and see if the state is changing. The click may fire before the checked property is updated making you think it's not working.

Comment: I'm actually going to be persisting something to the database and fire off an ajax call on the toggle between the states. That was out of scope for the question, though.